# How to add Hour wise data to stacked chart in powerbi

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have sensor data that storing in table storage and this data is used as the data source for Powerbi. The data contains 6 data for a DateTime hour. For example 50 for 2019-10-24 12:10 Am, 65 for 2019-10-24 12:20 Am etc
[image]

I want to show the graph as the following format where Y axis shows 10th mint, 20th mint to 50th mint of an hour
[image]
Is it possible to create such graph in PowerBi? I am new to PowerBi
I tried one and got the following result
[image]

The query is like

```
let
Source = AzureStorage.Tables("https://xxxxx.table.core.windows.net"),
AveragedResult1 = Source{[Name="AveragedResult"]}[Data],
#"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(AveragedResult1, "Content", {"DayID", "DeviceDayID", "Leq", "max", "min", "date"}, {"Content.DayID", "Content.DeviceDayID", "Content.Leq", "Content.max", "Content.min", "Content.date"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Content", each ([PartitionKey] = "2019-10-21" ))
in
   #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Is the time column set to the time data type? If not getting it converted is probably your first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a 10 min bin.. and then have that column as your y axis and hour for x axis.